# How do you pass a variable while using simplexml_load_file?

Tags: php, post, simplexml

I am pretty new to PHP so excuse my question as the answer will more then likely come easy to the people that are in this community.

I have a variable set up to retrieve a users text input from a form. I have set a variable up for this and simple used the $_POST function. I am now trying to pass the input into a another variable that is loading a XML file whitch then gets loaded through the simplexml_load_file function.

I am receive a error so I was hoping someone good hopefully help me out.

My current code:

```
<?php

$videoUSERNAME = $_POST['username'];
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$videoUSERNAME/uploads?max-results=50';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$media = $sxml->entry->children('media', true);
parse_str(parse_url((string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $vidArr);
?>
```

Comment: You can start off by removing all those <br /> tags att the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
    throw new RuntimeException('No username set!');
}
$feedURL = sprintf('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%s/uploads?max-results=50',
    rawurlencode($_POST['username']));
```

The reason your original code was not working at all is that you were attempting to interpolate a variable into a single-quoted string. This does not work. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick response(never emailed me for the notification :P). The errors have now been reduced but have this new one now:    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No username set!'